# SQLITE moving average

Tags: sqlite, date-arithmetic, moving-average

Trying to get the **moving average** on a per X months basis using SQLite.
Problem is i cannot seem to figure or find anything remotely useful on how to aggregate with a X month(s) lookback period and thus create a moving average.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE "nav" (
    `id`    TEXT,
    `nav`   NUMERIC,
    `date`  TEXT
);
```

Sample data

```
id      nav     date
1380    15.3    2005-01-09
1380    15.4    2005-01-16
1380    15.5    2005-01-23
1380    15.55   2005-01-30
1380    15.66   2005-02-06
1380    15.45   2005-02-13
1380    15.26   2005-02-20
1380    15.14   2005-02-27
1380    14.95   2005-03-06
1380    15.24   2005-03-13
1380    15.6    2005-03-20
1380    15.7    2005-03-27
1380    15.86   2005-04-03
1380    15.78   2005-04-10
1380    15.58   2005-04-17
1380    15.84   2005-04-24
1380    15.88   2005-05-01
1380    16.2    2005-05-08
1380    16.29   2005-05-15
1380    16.32   2005-05-22
1380    16.59   2005-05-29
1380    16.96   2005-06-05
1380    16.76   2005-06-12
1380    17.32   2005-06-19
1380    17.63   2005-06-26
1380    17.6    2005-07-03
1380    17.36   2005-07-10
1380    17.36   2005-07-17
1380    17.27   2005-07-24
1380    16.86   2005-07-31
1380    16.68   2005-08-07
1380    17.21   2005-08-14
1380    16.87   2005-08-21
1380    16.52   2005-08-28
1380    16.77   2005-09-04
1380    17.1    2005-09-11
1380    17.37   2005-09-18
1380    17.29   2005-09-25
1380    17.24   2005-10-02
1380    17.52   2005-10-09
1380    17.72   2005-10-16
1380    17.65   2005-10-23
1380    18.18   2005-10-30
1380    18.31   2005-11-06
1380    18.42   2005-11-13
1380    18.13   2005-11-20
1380    18.12   2005-11-27
1380    17.92   2005-12-04
1380    17.74   2005-12-11
1380    17.93   2005-12-18
1380    17.94   2005-12-25
1380    17.39   2006-01-01
1380    17.4    2006-01-08
1380    17.37   2006-01-15
1380    17.22   2006-01-22
1380    17.47   2006-01-29
1380    17.53   2006-02-05
1380    17.77   2006-02-12
1380    17.95   2006-02-19
1380    17.85   2006-02-26
1380    17.88   2006-03-05
1380    17.42   2006-03-12
1380    17.71   2006-03-19
1380    17.71   2006-03-26
1380    17.53   2006-04-02
1380    17.54   2006-04-09
1380    17.21   2006-04-16
1380    16.84   2006-04-23
1380    16.68   2006-04-30
1380    16.59   2006-05-07
1380    16.82   2006-05-14
1380    16.72   2006-05-21
1380    16.34   2006-05-28
1380    16.72   2006-06-04
1380    16.83   2006-06-11
1380    16.84   2006-06-18
1380    16.54   2006-06-25
1380    16.41   2006-07-02
1380    16.76   2006-07-09
1380    16.77   2006-07-16
1380    16.69   2006-07-23
1380    16.48   2006-07-30
1380    16.65   2006-08-06
1380    16.61   2006-08-13
1380    16.78   2006-08-20
1380    16.88   2006-08-27
1380    17.03   2006-09-03
1380    16.9    2006-09-10
1380    16.85   2006-09-17
1380    17.04   2006-09-24
1380    17.1    2006-10-01
1380    17.28   2006-10-08
1380    17.02   2006-10-15
1380    16.91   2006-10-22
1380    16.85   2006-10-29
1380    16.53   2006-11-05
1380    16.53   2006-11-12
1380    16.17   2006-11-19
1380    15.87   2006-11-26
1380    15.94   2006-12-03
1380    16.22   2006-12-10
1380    16.07   2006-12-17
1380    16.09   2006-12-24
1380    16.42   2006-12-31
1380    16.54   2007-01-07
1380    16.57   2007-01-14
1380    16.61   2007-01-21
1380    16.5    2007-01-28
1380    16.53   2007-02-04
1380    16.67   2007-02-11
1380    16.73   2007-02-18
1380    16.71   2007-02-25
1380    16.81   2007-03-04
1380    16.54   2007-03-11
1380    16.59   2007-03-18
1380    16.67   2007-03-25
1380    16.42   2007-04-01
1380    16.35   2007-04-08
1380    16.11   2007-04-15
1380    15.96   2007-04-22
1380    16.1    2007-04-29
1380    16.3    2007-05-06
1380    16.33   2007-05-13
1380    16.35   2007-05-20
1380    16.61   2007-05-27
1380    16.62   2007-06-03
1380    16.92   2007-06-10
1380    16.57   2007-06-17
1380    16.43   2007-06-24
1380    16.17   2007-07-01
1380    15.95   2007-07-08
1380    15.97   2007-07-15
1380    16.23   2007-07-22
1380    16.17   2007-07-29
1380    16.36   2007-08-05
1380    16.68   2007-08-12
1380    16.61   2007-08-19
1380    16.57   2007-08-26
1380    16.4    2007-09-02
1380    16.16   2007-09-09
1380    15.83   2007-09-16
1380    15.71   2007-09-23
1380    15.73   2007-09-30
1380    15.6    2007-10-07
1380    15.61   2007-10-14
1380    15.55   2007-10-21
1380    15.57   2007-10-28
1380    15.44   2007-11-04
1380    15.47   2007-11-11
1380    15.4    2007-11-18
1380    15.52   2007-11-25
1380    15.7    2007-12-02
1380    15.96   2007-12-09
1380    16.1    2007-12-16
1380    15.78   2007-12-23
1380    15.55   2007-12-30
1380    15.6    2008-01-06
1380    15.82   2008-01-13
1380    15.83   2008-01-20
1380    15.68   2008-01-27
1380    16.01   2008-02-03
1380    15.61   2008-02-10
1380    15.46   2008-02-17
1380    15.2    2008-02-24
1380    15.1    2008-03-02
1380    14.89   2008-03-09
1380    15.02   2008-03-16
1380    14.69   2008-03-23
1380    14.69   2008-03-30
1380    14.67   2008-04-06
1380    14.75   2008-04-13
1380    14.75   2008-04-20
1380    15      2008-04-27
1380    14.88   2008-05-04
1380    14.87   2008-05-11
1380    14.6    2008-05-18
1380    14.88   2008-05-25
1380    15      2008-06-01
1380    15.07   2008-06-08
1380    15      2008-06-15
1380    14.81   2008-06-22
1380    14.84   2008-06-29
1380    14.74   2008-07-06
1380    14.82   2008-07-13
1380    14.98   2008-07-20
1380    15.06   2008-07-27
1380    15.52   2008-08-03
1380    15.64   2008-08-10
1380    15.69   2008-08-17
1380    15.95   2008-08-24
1380    16.44   2008-08-31
1380    16.77   2008-09-07
1380    16.48   2008-09-14
1380    16.44   2008-09-21
1380    17.49   2008-09-28
1380    17.66   2008-10-05
1380    18.44   2008-10-12
1380    19.42   2008-10-19
1380    19.34   2008-10-26
1380    19.62   2008-11-02
1380    19.57   2008-11-09
1380    20.77   2008-11-16
1380    20.18   2008-11-23
1380    20.97   2008-11-30
1380    19.96   2008-12-07
1380    19.4    2008-12-14
1380    19.6    2008-12-21
1380    19.46   2008-12-28
1380    19.75   2009-01-04
1380    20.31   2009-01-11
1380    20.78   2009-01-18
1380    20.56   2009-01-25
```

Basically i would want... (fake data)

```
id      nav     date            average_6m
1380    15.6    2008-01         14.1
1380    15.61   2008-02         14.12
1380    14.69   2008-03         14.2
1380    15      2008-04         14.5
1380    14.88   2008-05         14.4
1380    14.84   2008-06         14.3
1380    15.06   2008-07         14.6
1380    16.44   2008-08         15.2
1380    17.49   2008-09         15.9
1380    19.34   2008-10         16.4
1380    20.97   2008-11         18.4
1380    19.46   2008-12         18.2
1380    20.56   2009-01         18.4
```

#### Challenges

1. `date` isn't on a per-day structure, some intervalls even doesn't have all the work days in each month so have to use MAX() day on each month in order to get last value etc
2. If there is no X month lookback the average must be/must get `null`

Comment: Average of what? How would you compute it?

Comment: Average per X months back ie 6 months. So if it's month `X` lookback period would be `X-5` months.
I would compute it by `current_row_average = (this.value + prev5.value)/6` (pseudo code, one would of course have to get all previous 5 and not the faux prev5).

Comment: But there are not exactly six rows for six months.

Comment: If X months lookback does not exist fill with null values. The MA (Moving Average) can of course only be started once there are this X number of requested entries in existence. And there are six rows for six months if one only include the last datapoint for each month using something like MAX().

Here's a visual JS example of how a MA50 and MA200 would work on the Apple Stock price (it's using days and not months though). http://jsfiddle.net/WaEBc/160

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" answer to this seems to be "don't".

Since i'm using sqlite + php i figured it was simpler and more perfomant to do this with PHP instead, so i created a simple helper function for it:

```
/**
*   Moving average calculations
*   @param $arr: array with princing data
*   @param $ma: moving average; no. of rows
*   @param $nav: key for pricing data
*/

function sma( $arr, $ma=6, $nav='nav' ){


    foreach( $arr as $key => $val ){

        $avg = 0;
        $average = 0;

        // check if look-back period, else set 0
        if( $key-$ma > -2 ) {

            // create lookback period
            $range = range(0,$ma-1);

            foreach($range as $r){
                $tmp = $key - $r;
                $avg = $avg + $arr[$tmp][$nav];
            }

            // round with 2 decimal point
            $average = round( ($avg/$ma) * 100 ) / 100;         

        }

        // add to current key
        $newkey = 'sma'.$ma;
        $arr[$key][$newkey] = $average;

    }


    return $arr;

} // sma()
```

Since we're using arrays in PHP the performance hit is negliable and probably less then it would be to calculate it using SQLite.

Screen of result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, filter out any rows that are not the last in the month.
Then use a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq) to compute the moving average; the condition with the `m3` subquery ensures that the `AVG()` subquery does not find any rows if there are not exactly six.

```
WITH months(id, nav, date) AS (
  SELECT id, nav, MAX(date)
  FROM nav
  GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date)
)
SELECT id,
       nav,
       strftime('%Y-%m', date),
       (SELECT AVG(nav)
        FROM months AS m2
        WHERE m2.date BETWEEN date(months.date, 'start of month', '-5 months')
                          AND months.date
          AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM months AS m3
               WHERE m3.date BETWEEN date(months.date, 'start of month', '-5 months')
                                 AND months.date
              ) = 6
       ) AS average_6m
FROM months;
```

Comment: Thanks -- that might work, but i can in no way test it since i don't have any means to run that query. All my tools die when i run it. :)

Do note that the table `nav` currently contains `851 000` rows.